# Installing ruby app (OpenProject) fails on generating secret token; wrong argument type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arguments, rake, failed-installation

I'm trying to install OpenProject on shared hosting. I'm following [these instructions](https://www.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_OpenProject_3_0) but I got stuck on steps 3.7 and 3.8 getting this:

```
Bundler.require... rake aborted!
TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Fixnum)
```

I managed to update the ruby version to the latest (2.1.2) and installed the gems correctly. What could the problem be?

this is my trace:

```
[~/public_html/openproject]# bundle exec rake generate_secret_token --trace
require 'rails/all'... 0.770s
Bundler.require... rake aborted!
TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Fixnum)
~/ruby/gems/gems/rabl-0.9.3/lib/rabl/configuration.rb:22:in `default_options='
~/ruby/gems/gems/rabl-0.9.3/lib/rabl/configuration.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
~/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
~/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
~/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
~/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rabl-0.9.3/lib/rabl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
~/public_html/openproject/config/application.rb:68:in `block in <top (required)>'
~/public_html/openproject/config/application.rb:44:in `block in bench'
~/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
~/public_html/openproject/config/application.rb:43:in `bench'
~/public_html/openproject/config/application.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
~/public_html/openproject/Rakefile:33:in `require'
~/public_html/openproject/Rakefile:33:in `<top (required)>'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
~/ruby/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
~/ruby/gems/bin/rake:23:in `load'
~/ruby/gems/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

same happens for `bundle exec rake db:create:all`

Answer (score 0):

Try `rake secret` instead, and copy the result, it's a long random string of alphanumeric characters.

Edit `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`:

`AppName::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'SECRET_TOKEN'`

where the result is pasted between the single quotes where `SECRET_TOKEN` is in the line above.

Your Rails app probably already has a value here, replace it if so desired.

Comment: Sorry. Same error after trying this. It happens with `db:create` too so I don't think it's rake that has the problem. Man these ruby application installations are always so hard.